# cakephp $this->Form->input not recognising a Text column on live server

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a weird issue which is only happening on my live server, on my localhost the form input is working as expected. The files are all the same and the database is an export/import of my localhost one.

if you go to you will see the details of a user. The 'Personal Details' input should be a text area. That column has the type text in both databases so how come it's not picking up that fact in the online version?

My localhost is php 5.3.1

the live server is php 5.2.17

Strangely I have another table with the same column type and it works just fine

The personal_details column should just be detected by cakephp as a textarea shouldn't it? There's nothing else cake needs to know that is there?

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's a caching issue - your server has the old version of your model/table cached, so doesn't know about the new field or it's type. Clear your cache on the live server.

One easy way to do this is to set debug to 2 on your server, then refresh the page. After that, you should set debug back to zero.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you thank you. I'd been trying to fix that for a couple of hours.

Comment: No problem. For future reference, whenever something is working locally but not on the live server, the cache is the first thing to check.

Comment: I'll be looking in there in future. Thanks again :)